# What reasons are there (other than oxygen) Tardigrades can't survive Mars?

Tags: mars, colonization, atmosphere, life, terraforming

[If Cyanobacteria or Lichens can survive on Mars](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/32633/is-there-any-reason-cyanobacteria-or-lichens-cant-survive-on-mars) could other small organisms like the [Tardigrade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tardigrade) then survive & flourish among them?

> Due to the thicker atmosphere to be found the bottom of the [Hellas Planitia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hellas_Planitia) & [Valles Marineris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valles_Marineris) (both around 7 km deep) those are the particular areas I'm thinking of.

So to word the question more explicitly I'm asking if.

Oxygen aside are there any other obvious contraindications for the ability of tardigrades & similar organisms to survive & thrive on Mars (most particularly in the Hellas Planitia & Valles Marineris)?

> We know from answers to [this question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/32503/how-deep-a-valley-or-trench-would-be-needed-on-mars-to-provide-the-same-atmosphe) atmospheric pressure at the bottom of Hellas Planitia is 1.16 kPa : well below the [Armstrong limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armstrong_limit)'s 6.3 kPa.

Some other tardigrade links.
[American Scientist](https://www.americanscientist.org/article/tardigrades)
[BBC](http://www.bbc.co.uk/earth/story/20150313-the-toughest-animals-on-earth)
[ResearchGate](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/319213582_Can_tardigrades_theoretically_survive_on_Mars)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87322/discussion-between-pelinore-and-uhoh).

Comment: It would be much easier and cheaper to expose tardigrades to a simulated martian atmosphere on Earth than to the real atmosphere of Mars. If they do not survive the simulation it does not make sense to send them to Mars after that. But for reproduction they need not only a survivable atmosphere, they need something organic to eat.

Comment: Since Wiki says they live on plant material and bacteria, which both haven't been found on Mars, you may conclude they can't grow and multiply.  But I think they certainly have a chance surviving on Mars when they would be among *Nostoc commune* ! https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/26954/what-type-of-rock-or-soil-on-mars-will-give-nostoc-commune-cyanobacteria-the-best